# Cancel in Spectrum Colorpicker Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, spectrumjs

im using spectrum.js color picker only cancel event is not working on which i have to reset the color to inital one since im getting previewElement null.how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cancel changes to the preview you have use [events](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events) like this:

```
var isChanged = false;
$("#picker").spectrum({
    move : function (tinycolor) {
        // apply the changes to previewElement 
    },
    show : function (tinycolor) {
        isChanged = false;
        previousСolor = tinycolo
    },
    hide : function (tinycolor) {
        if (!isChanged && previousСolor) {
            // revert the changes in the previewElement 
        }
    },
    change : function (tinycolor) {
        isChanged = true;
        // apply the changes to previewElement 
    }
});
```

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dgk3507b/3/).